# c# ToDictionary with ContainsKey check

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lambda, duplicates

I have a list that I want to put in a dictionary, for simplicity the values being inserted will all be the same.

I can use a foreach loop.

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("Earth");
    list.Add("Wind");
    list.Add("Fire");
    list.Add("Water");
    list.Add("Water"); // Will NOT BE INSERTED using the foreach loop

    var myDictionary= new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach (string value in list)
    {
        if (!myDictionary.ContainsKey(value))
        {
        myDictionary.Add(value, 1);
        }
    }
```

The above works.

But I want to use ToDictionary do the same in the following way -

```
    Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary2 = list.ToDictionary(i => i, i => 1);
```

Of course this fails because I'm adding "Water" twice.

What is the correct way of checking for duplicate entries when using ToDictionary?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `Distinct()` to filter out duplicates:

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary2 = list.Distinct().ToDictionary(i => i, i => 1);
```

The same approach would make your traditional loop much clearer too, since you don't have to check "manually" for duplicates:

```
foreach (string value in list.Distinct())
{
    myDictionary.Add(value, 1);
}
```

Comment: @Gabe: Not sure I don't understand your comment in the context of the question - can you clarify?

Comment: A dictionary where all the values are 1 is essentially just a set. If the user never accesse the values, an actual dictionary is not necessary.

Comment: @Gabe: unless of course he's going to then use it to store counts (not that the OP appears to). Add the `HashSet` answer.

Comment: Yes - I took the comment *"for simplicity the values being inserted will all be the same"* to mean that OP does in fact need values - otherwise just a `HashSet<string>` would do the job w/o any need for checking for distinct values at all.

Comment: When developing the real app the values stored in the dictionary will vary. I just wanted to keep the question short.

Comment: @Bryan: What is your real requirement then?

Comment: The real requirement is to find a good "way of checking for duplicate entries when using ToDictionary?"

Answer (score 11):

`Distinct` is one option that avoids the duplicate key issue. If you need a count of duplicates, you might try something more like this `GroupBy` as follows:

```
var dict = list.GroupBy(i => i).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

If your application is not just a simple string-list/duplicate-count structure, you might get some mileage from choosing a different structure like a `Lookup` that you can get from calling the `ToLookup` extension -or possibly going with a Grouping like the `GroupBy` I used above.